# A different layout is not displayed the first time you start the application

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm starting to study android and I'm having this problem:

The first (only first) time I run my application, only activity_main is displayed. It has a navigation bar, but it is empty.

My application is designed for audiobooks. It has the sections "Last Audiobooks", "Favorites Audiobooks", "Saved Audiobooks", "All Audiobooks". At the first launch they are all empty.

The code below, I've deleted everything not related to layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper; 
private Fragment selectedFragment = new BooksLastFragment();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);  navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BooksLastFragment()).commit();}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_last:
                    selectedFragment = new BooksLastFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_favourites:
                    selectedFragment = new BooksFavouritesFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_all:
                    selectedFragment = new BooksAllFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_remote:
                    selectedFragment = new GenresFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

            return true;
        };

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    DialogFragment dialogAbout;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            dialogAbout = new AboutFragment();
            dialogAbout.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogAbout");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}}
```

Image:

First launch -
[image]

After reload - 
[image]

Sorry for bad english and bad code

Comment: what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: you have described your app, but not the problem? do you want to show somethig else the first time, or do you just want the lists to be hidden? cause you can just set visibility = gone on the elements you want to hide

Comment: I want to show books the first time, but he don't show

Answer (score 0):

try this and if its help then let me know. In this code, I have called the first fragment which I wanted to load for the first time when my apps start in the onCreate method by checking null too. And if you find this difficult in understanding then let me know. Happy coding...

```
 private Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new BooksLastFragment();;
                loadFragment(fragment);
            }
    }

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_last:
                    Fragment fragment1 =new BooksLastFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction1.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment1);
                    transaction1.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_favourites:
                    Fragment fragment2 =new BooksFavouritesFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction2.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2);
                    transaction2.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_all:
                    //toolbar.setTitle("Favourite");
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_remote:
                    //toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

This is the main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have to replace "R.id.discover" with id layout last books, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly and I have also made changes in code w.r.t your code content. Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: It's stopped starting up. The debugger writes: 
"No view found for id 0x7f08005c (audiobooks:id/fragment_container) for fragment BooksLastFragment{33a125f #0 id=0x7f08005c}"

Comment: Since we had defined every fragment in frame layout so give to frame layout like this 'android:id="@+id/frame_container"'. I have also provided the layout of main activity.

Comment: Still the same error, but thank you very much for your help